# How to draw a transparent shape with dash border

Tags: java, awt, transparency, shapes, graphics2d

I have been using the java api 2D, i'm trying to figure out how to make  my square fill with a mirror effect color, For example,

```
g.drawRect(0,0,40,40)
g.fill(Color) //is it possible to get a translucid color? like a mirror effect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the `Stroke` used by the `Graphics` context when it draws a `Shape`.  Take a look at [Stroking and Filling Graphics Primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html) for more details